# SQL Offset based on ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, offset

Trying to find 3 rows based on a users ID.

The results should be offset with the current user and the row before and after:

```
87. John Snow 1000p
88. YOU 990p
89. Jane Doe 900p
```

I have the user variable stored in `@currentUser` and using the below query which fetches all the relevant actions:

```
SELECT u.UserID, 
       u.ContentID,  
       (u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName) AS theUser, 
       SUM( l.Action ) as thePoints 
FROM   [AccessLog] l 
       LEFT JOIN [User] u 
           ON l.UserID = u.UserID 
WHERE  l.Action = 13 
       OR l.Action = 2 
       AND l.Timestamp BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '2014-09-01') AND CONVERT(datetime, '2014-09-11') 
GROUP BY u.UserID, 
       u.ContentID, 
       u.FirstName, 
       u.LastName 
ORDER BY thePoints DESC
```

How would I go about listing eg. #87 to #89 if my place is #88 ?

Comment: You are talking about User Id's?

Comment: Added SQL Server based on the non-standard syntax

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking at `OFFSET` and `FETCH FIRST`, though I believe that it is dependent on version of the database you are using.

```
SELECT u.UserID, 
       u.ContentID,  
       (u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName) AS theUser, 
       SUM( l.Action ) as thePoints 
FROM   [AccessLog] l 
       LEFT JOIN [User] u 
           ON l.UserID = u.UserID 
WHERE  l.Action = 13 
       OR l.Action = 2 
       AND l.Timestamp BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '2014-09-01') AND CONVERT(datetime, '2014-09-11') 
GROUP BY u.UserID, 
       u.ContentID, 
       u.FirstName, 
       u.LastName 
ORDER BY thePoints DESC
offset 87 rows
fetch first 3 rows only
```

Comment: If the position isn't known before the query is run. How would this be possible? The user could be in posistion 7 or 87.

Comment: You could create a parameter `@position` and populate this with the position of the provided person, then change the `OFFSET 87 ROWS` to be something like `OFFSET (@position - 1) ROWS`